# Installing mailutils - interface

Tags: email, emacs

I'm trying to install mailutils and ran `sudo apt-get install mailutils`.  It began installing, but now I have the following strange interface that appeared on my terminal:

[image: mail screenshot]

I can scroll up and down using Emacs keyboard commands, but that's it.  I can't find any documentation on what to do from here, nor do I know how to actually select anything.

Comment: Press **Tab** and hit **OK** and move on with the configuration. This is just a notice or message

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Ah, the tab key.  Thanks!